# Most effecient way of doing searching in a database

Tags: php, jquery, database, postgresql

I have a Form Page then in the form there is phone number, age, postcode fields and I have a generate button. When the user generates the button I will auto-populate the questions in the form. These questions are survey questions and required some conditions whether I will show it in the form or not.

I can do all the logic. My questions is the best way to approach this validation that I will explain.

I have `Questions` table with `id, question, column_header`.

I have `Suppressions` table with `id, phone, column_header`.

The validation is if the phone number in the form is already in the suppression table together with a column header name that question should not be shown when you click the generate button.

Ex.

```
Questions
id | question | column_header|
___|__________|______________|
1  | test1    | ques1

Suppression
id | phone | column_header |
___|_______|_______________|
1  | 1234  | ques1
```

So example that the phone number in the form is `1234` then I click the generate button, my jQuery and Ajax will handle this. I will loop in each question and for each qestion I will query in the `Suppression` table if that current question column header is already in that table together with the phone number and if it does then I won't enable or show the question.

That will do the job, my concern is what if the suppression table grows like millions of records and I have 30 questions. So for each question I will now need to search in the million records in the suppresion table just to find a match if I will be needing to disable or enable a question and the process per ajax call will be slow.

Is there a better way to do this? I am using PHP Laravel and Postgre as my database.

Answer (score 0):

Millions of records is nothing for RDBMS. You use a subquery in your main SQL statement to query the Suppresion table. Your subquery returns `count(*)` after filtering `phone` and `column_header`. Then you check whether the result of subquery is zero or not. You main SQL matches in `Questions` table only if the value of subquery is zero.

Example:
`select * from Questions where column_header="yyy" 0=(select count(*) from Suppresion where phone="xxx" and column_header="yyy")`

Answer (score 0):

As tcak pointed out Millions of records is not a problem for modern databases, however it still helps to think about how you are accessing you data.

Even without millions of records what you have planned is quite inefficient and even with a small database the network traffic might make your app slow.

Instead since you know the phone number on page load, why not load all questions for a particular phone number and keep that information on the page, tehn when your user clicks a row, you can check your inbrowser info.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help sorry I didn't make it clear. The phone number will not appear on page load. The phone number is an input from the user before the user clicks the generate question button. Is there any alternative? Thanks!

Comment: The answer is the same you have the phone number as an input.

Comment: Hmm I'm a little confuse, you say that load all the questions as the page loads? But it's not possbile to load the question on page load coz I need the input for phone number right? So what will happen is the same logic that I stated in my question?